# SSRS Returns Wrong End Date Parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

From my internet page/portal I generate my report:

> http://localhost/BOPortal/Reports/View/Events?FromDate=2016-06-22%2022:00:00&ToDate=2016-06-23%2021:59:00&Language=en-GB&User=admin

When it is run the ToDate parameter is wrong. It gives me the date from the URL plus one day 24/06/2016 21:58:59.

Why?

Comment: what does your query look like where your parameter is passed, do you have an expression for your parameter?

Comment: no i don't have expression. Just i pass parameter from my url into report.